Постоянно приходится запускать venv в pycharm
Несмотря на то, что, при создании проекта, я указал interpreter type: Project venv, мне все равно приходится прописывать venv\Sctipts\activate, если хочу установить новые модули через pip. . Подскажите, пожалуйста.
